# How to print particular cases with Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I would like to perform the following simplification:

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[Exp[I*u*theta]*Exp[I*v*theta]*Sin[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}], 
 Assumptions -> {u \[Element] Integers, v \[Element] Integers}],
```

which returns

```
-((1 + (-1)^(u + v))/((-1 + u + v) (1 + u + v)))
```

However, `Integrate` does not treat the particular cases when `u + v = +/- 1`. Do you have any idea how to **detect** print these cases, as well? It would also be useful if `FullSimplify` printed `(u + v)^2 - 1` instead of `(-1 + u + v) (1 + u + v)`.

Comment: These give divide by zero. You can do `Simplify[sol, {u + v == -1}]` where `sol` is the result if the `FullSimplify` there. Same for `u+v==1` it gives divide by zero. As to the other question about using `(u + v)^2 - 1` instead of `(-1 + u + v) (1 + u + v)`, I am not sure. It seems Mathematica likes the factored form more.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBfyQ.png)

Comment: @Nasser, yes but this integral exists even if `u+v= +/- 1`. In these cases, they can be evaluated in another way.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int = Assuming[{u ∈ Integers, v ∈ Integers}, 
  Integrate[Exp[I*u*theta]*Exp[I*v*theta]*Sin[theta], {theta, 0, π}]]

(* -((1 + (-1)^(u + v))/((-1 + u + v) (1 + u + v))) *)
```

To rearrange the denominator,

```
int2 = Simplify[int /. u -> t - v] /. t -> u + v

(* -((1 + (-1)^(u + v))/(-1 + (u + v)^2)) *)
```

The integral is real when

```
Assuming[{u ∈ Integers, v ∈ Integers}, 
 FunctionDomain[int2, {u, v}] // Simplify]

(* (u + v)^2 != 1 *)
```

To handle the limiting cases of `u + v == ±1`

```
int3 = Piecewise @@ {{
    {Limit[Simplify[int /. u -> t - v], t -> 1], u + v == 1},
    {Limit[Simplify[int /. u -> t - v], t -> -1], u + v == -1}},
   int2}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternatively,

```
Simplify[
  Piecewise[{Assuming[{u ∈ Integers, v ∈ Integers, #}, 
        Integrate[
         Exp[I*u*theta]*Exp[I*v*theta]*Sin[theta], 
          {theta, 0, π}]], #} & /@ 
   {u + v == 1, u + v == -1, True}] /. u -> t - v] /. t -> u + v
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this answer is more useful than the other. However, it would be even more helpful if `Integrate` provided the special cases. I saw the `GenerateConditions` command, but it does not work properly in this situation.

Comment: Perhaps it would be sufficient if the integral could be evaluated subject to the `(u+v)^2=1` condition. Is there any chance to return the output of this conditional integral?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It seems that Mathematica cannot handle `(u+v)^2=1` directly, right?

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

> yes but this integral exists even if u+v= +/- 1

Then do the following

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
integrand = Exp[I*u*theta]*Exp[I*v*theta]*Sin[theta]
sol = Integrate[integrand, {theta, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[sol, u -> 1 - v]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[sol, u -> -1 - v]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same result is obtained using your original input

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
integrand = Exp[I*u*theta]*Exp[I*v*theta]*Sin[theta];
sol = FullSimplify[Integrate[integrand, {theta, 0, Pi}], 
  Assumptions -> {u ∈ Integers, v ∈ Integers}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This solution assumes that I know what kind of particular cases occur. I would like to *detect* these particular cases via Mathematica.